# why this value inside class method not equal to object itself?

Tags: javascript, class, object

I have confusion on this.

```
class Func {
  greet() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}
let g = new Func();
console.log(g.greet()===g);
```

I thought `this` value is pointing to the newly created object itself but it returns false.

But if i do this -

```
class Func {
  greet() {
    console.log(this===g);
  }
}
let g = new Func();
console.log(g.greet());
```

It returns true.

Then why the first one is false. Can anyone explain what’s really happen?

Comment: `g.greet()` does *log* the `this` value, it *does not* `return` it. You are comparing `undefined === g`.

Comment: Oh got it. Sorry my mistake. I should have return it instead consoling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log(this)` will only log the value and `returns undefined ( implicit return )`, you need to return `this`

```js
class Func {
  greet() {
    console.log(this);
    return this
  }
}
let g = new Func();
console.log(g.greet()===g);
```